# Send the Content of DIV with php mail form

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create an email form with a cart that then sends the Summary of the Cart displayed to the user. How can i send the content of the cart div?

I am using a E-Mail form i found online that works with bootstrap 4. It has the function to grab all active form fields and send those. The thing is once i use a checkbox it displays these as on or off and not the value e.g yes or no. I found solutions but am not sure on how to implement those.

```html
<div class="form-group font" id="cart" style="border: 5px solid white; width: 40%; padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                            <h5>&Uuml;bersicht</h5>
                            <div id="descript10">Vorname: <b id="vorname"></b></div>
                            <div id="descript11">Nachname: <b id="nachname"></b></div>
                            <div id="descript12">Alter: <b id="alter"></b></div>
                            <div id="descript1">Buchen: <b id="booking">Nein</b></div>
                            <div id="descript2" style="display:none;">Preisklasse: <b id="type"></b></div>
                            <div id="descript3" style="display:none;">Alles: <b id="all">Ja</b></div>
                            <div id="descript4" style="display:none;">Mischpult: <b id="mixer">Ja</b></div>
                            <div id="descript5" style="display:none;">Anlage: <b id="sound">Ja</b></div>
                            <div id="descript6" style="display:none;">Lichteffekte: <b id="light">Ja</b></div>
                            <div id="descript7" style="display:none;">Nebelmaschine: <b id="fog">Ja</b></div>
                            <div id="descript8" style="display:none;">Nachricht: <b id="nachricht"></b></div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Abschicken" data-disable="true">
                        <p class="text-muted font">
                            <strong>*</strong> Pflichtfelder
                        </p>
```

```php
<?php
// require ReCaptcha class
require('recaptcha-master/src/autoload.php');

// configure
// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$from = 'example2@mail.com';

// an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
$sendTo = 'example@mail.com';

// subject of the email
$subject = 'New message';

// form field names and their translations.
// array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$fields = array('name' => 'Vorname', 'surname' => 'Nachname', 'email' => 'Email', 'buchen' => 'Buchen?', 'options' => 'Optionen', 'mischpult' => 'Mischpult', 'anlage' => 'Anlage', 'licht' => 'Lichteffekte', 'nebel' => 'Nebelmaschine', 'message' => 'Nachricht');

// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage = 'Deine Nachricht wurde erfolgreich gesendet. Ich melde mich so bald wie möglich!';

// If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
$errorMessage = 'Es gab einen Fehler beim senden deiner Nachricht. Versuche es Später nochmal.';

// ReCaptch Secret
$recaptchaSecret = 'secret';

// let's do the sending

// if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try {
    if (!empty($_POST)) {

        // validate the ReCaptcha, if something is wrong, we throw an Exception,
        // i.e. code stops executing and goes to catch() block

        if (!isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
            throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha is not set.');
        }

        // do not forget to enter your secret key from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin

        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($recaptchaSecret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost());

        // we validate the ReCaptcha field together with the user's IP address

        $response = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        if (!$response->isSuccess()) {
            throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha wurde nicht Validiert.');
        }

        // everything went well, we can compose the message, as usually

        $emailText = "You have a new message from your contact form\n=============================\n";

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email
            if (isset($fields[$key])) {
                $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
            }
        }

        // All the neccessary headers for the email.
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
            'From: ' . $from,
            'Reply-To: ' . $from,
            'Return-Path: ' . $from,
        );

        // Send email
        mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

        $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $e->getMessage());
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
} else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

So i want to get the content of the div in the mail instead of every single value that is active. I'm no expert, but i'm guessing the foreach function needs to be replaced by a get function to get the content. I just don't know how. The form works, just not the way i want it to. live version can be found here: https://nichola1.myhostpoint.ch/DJ101/contact.php

Comment: Please describe the actual result and how it is different from the expected one. Generally, using `mail` for send emails is an outdated technique (will probably get blocked by antispam robots) so I'd suggest you to use some dedicated library like SwiftMailer

Comment: Swiftmailer looks promising. I'll look into that. I wasn't aware that mail was outdated.